# I'm asked to find laurent series of f(z) with given anulus, and i saw that the singularities of f(z) its not on anulus

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

find laurent series of $\frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^3(2z+3)}$ in $0<|z|<1$.

the singularities are at $z=0$ and $z=\frac{3}{2}$.

can I just do this?:

$\frac{1}{z^3(2z+3)}$ $(1-\cos(z))$ = $\frac{1}{z^3(2z+3)}$ $\left[1-\left(1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+...\right)\right]$

(because in $0<|z|<1$ ,$\frac{1}{z^3(2z+3)}$ well defined(?))

Comment: You have to develop a Laurent series around the singularity $\;z=0\;$, and you didn't do that., BTW, the other singularity is at $\;z=-\frac32\;$ , and...can you say what kind of singularity is $\;z=0\;$ ?

Comment: yea my bad its z=-3/2, i dont know what kind of singularity is z=0, give me some

Comment: I won't tell you since it is a nice exercise to calculate it yourself, either using limits and stuff or using basic power series of those functions.. As a hint I'll tell you that it is **not** a pole of order $\;3\;$ ...

Comment: is it pole of order 1, since i can factor z^2 from (1-cosz)'s series? and what i can do with that to solve this problem?

Comment: Indeed so. Nice!

Comment: Can it be simplified?

Answer (score 0):

this is what i got

$\frac{1-\cos(z)}{z^3(2z+3)}$ = $\frac1{z^3(2z+3)}$ $z^2(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{z^2}{4!}+\frac{z^4}{6!}-\frac{z^6}{8!}+...)$

= $\frac1{z(2z+3)}$ $(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{z^2}{4!}+\frac{z^4}{6!}-\frac{z^6}{8!}+...)$

and using partial fraction decomposition

= ($\frac{1}{3z}-\frac{2}{3(2z+3)}$)$(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{z^2}{4!}+\frac{z^4}{6!}-\frac{z^6}{8!}+...)$

=($\frac{1}{3z} -\frac{2}{3^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{-2z}{3})^n$) [$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+2)!}$]

from here I don't know what to do...any help?